# Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://www.server.com:1234/sites/test/

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

I want to create a list item using SharePoint Client object model (SharePoint 2010).

```
        string siteURL = @"https://www.server.com:1234/sites/test/";

        using (ClientContext spcontext = new ClientContext(siteURL))
        {
            // Connecting to SharePoint site
            spcontext.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "password", "domain");

            spcontext.RequestTimeout = 600000;

            spcontext.Load(spcontext.Web, w => w.Title, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl, w => w.Lists);
            spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.Write("Success");
        }
```

I am using above code to connect to SharePoint site, but it is throwing error Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://www.server.com:1234/sites/test/

Let me know where i dm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found my answer after lots of research. It was the problem related to Authorization, the SharePoint server which i wanted to refer, had a Form based Authentication. So i updated my code according to that and it worked fine.

Please find my below updated code

```
 using (ClientContext spcontext = new ClientContext("siteURL"))
        {
            spcontext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
            spcontext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo("UserName","Password");
            spcontext.Load(spcontext.Web, w => w.Title, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl, w => w.Lists);
            spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(spcontext.Web.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }
```

This is working fine.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with my code. The server in my case seems to have both the authentication modes enabled. I would like to know if in this case which authentication should I use to create clientcontext of my SP2010 site? FYI, I do not have access to server and I am writing a CSOM application to download the files from server. Regards
Agasthya